# Reactive extensions(Rx) Switch() produces new observable which is not subscribed to provided OnCompleted()

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx.net

I have a problem with my Rx subscription using Switch statement.

```
_performSearchSubject
            .AsObservable()
            .Select(_ => PerformQuery())
            .Switch()
            .ObserveOn(_synchronizationContextService.SynchronizationContext)
            .Subscribe(DataArrivedForPositions, PositionQueryError, PositionQueryCompleted)
            .DisposeWith(this);
```

The flow is:

1. Some properties change and the performSearchSubject.OnNext is called
2. The PerformPositionQuery() is called, which returns a observer each time it is hit
3. The service which responds through this observer calls OnNext twice and OnCompleted once when the data receive is done
4. Method DataArrivedForPositions is called twice as expected
5. Method PositionQueryCompleted is never called, though observer.OnCompleted() is called inside my data service.

Code for dataService is:

```
        protected override void Request(Request request, IObserver<Response> observer)
        {
            query.Arrive += p => QueryReceive(request.RequestId, p, observer, query);
            query.Error += (type, s, message) => QueryError(observer, message);
            query.NoMoreData += id => QueryCompleted(observer);

            query.Execute(request);
        }

        private void QueryError(IObserver<PositionSheetResponse> observer, string message)
        {
            observer.OnError(new Exception(message));
        }

        private void QueryCompleted(IObserver<PositionSheetResponse> observer)
        {
            observer.OnCompleted();
        }

        private void QueryReceive(Guid requestId, Qry0079Receive receiveData, IObserver<PositionSheetResponse> observer, IQry0079PositionSheet query)
        {
            observer.OnNext(ConvertToResponse(requestId, receiveData));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Switch` result will only Complete when your outer observable (`_performSearchSubject`) completes. I assume in your case this one never does (it's probably bound to a user action performing the search).

What's unclear is *when* you expect `PositionQueryCompleted` to be called. If It's after each and every successful query is processed, then your stream needs to be modified, because `Switch` lost you the information that the query stream completed, but it also lacks information about the UI (wrong scheduler even) to say whether its data was actually processed.

There may be other ways to achieve it, but basically you want your query stream complete to *survive* through `Switch` (which currently ignore this event). For instance you can transform your query stream to have n+1 events, with one extra for the complete:

```
    _performSearchSubject
        .AsObservable()
        .Select(_ => 
                  PerformQuery()
                  .Select(Data => new { Data, Complete = false})
                  .Concat(Observable.Return(new { Data = (string)null, Complete = true })))
```

You can safely apply `.Switch().ObserveOn(_synchronizationContextService.SynchronizationContext)` on it, but then you need to modify your subscription:

```
    .Subscribe(data => {
        if (data.Complete) DataArrivedForPositions(data.Data);
        else PositionQueryCompleted()
    }, PositionQueryError)
```

Comment: Your assumption is right! Each time I call performSearcsubject.OnNext() on button press and it creates a new observable that is consumed by switch. Though this subject never completes. I want the PositionQueryCompleted method to be called whenever the most recent query is successfully completed. Meaning inner observable OnCompleted() was called.

Comment: Added a solution, which assumes your query results object don't already include the 'completion information' because it's otherwise trivial.

Comment: First of all, many thanks to you! Secondly, I see your point and understand the grey spot on my thinking. Yet the question for me remains - how come the OnNext subscription is persisted on a fresher observable while OnError and OnCompleted are not? What I am missing there?

Comment: OnError is also persisted (pretty sure `Switch` will OnError if any of the inner streams errors), but OnComplete isn't, and can't be, because:
- it'd terminate the outer stream (no further OnNext allowed, in your case it'd mean no further search possible)
- Switch behavior would be undeterministic, because switching from one stream terminating to another would have *very* different behavior whether the first stream terminates before or after the second OnNext, and that wouldn't make this operator very useful

Comment: Enormous thanks for your effort now I have it properly figured out. Also, I was not expecting to get an answer for Rx so fast...

Comment: Remember the protocol for Rx is `OnNext* (OnError | OnCompleted)`. i.e. you can have 0, 1 or many `OnNext` call backs. Optionally you can have either an `OnError` or an `OnCompleted` callback following your 0-many `OnNext` callbacks. However, once you have had an `OnError` or an `OnCompleted` the sequence is terminal and must not produce any more callbacks. This is why your switch will not pass on the inner `OnCompleted` callbacks.